# Did I do row reduction correctly

Tags: linear-algebra

matrix with b in the right most column and row reduce to see if the system is consistent or not. Consistency would indicate yes and non consistency would indicate no. However given the matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 5& 2\\
-2& 1& -6& -1\\
0& 2& 8& 6\end{bmatrix}$

where $b$ is $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix}$ the book says that b cannot and is therefore inconsistent. However when I did row reduction I got a row of all zeros which NORMALLY indicates infinitely many solutions. What am I missing here? When does a row of all zeros not mean infinitely many solutions? Did I do elimination incorrectly?
work:
$\begin{array}{c}2r_1+r_2\\
-2r_2+r_3\end{array}$

leaving

$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 5& 2\\
0& 1& 4& 3\\
0& 0& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: the final matrix looks correct

Answer (score 2):

The matrix and $b$ you have written **are indeed consistent** exactly by your work shown.  Check that the numbers are the same as are intended and written in the exercise in the book.  Perhaps you are reading the solution to the problem next to it or took values for $b$ from an adjacent problem.  It is entirely possible also that the book itself contains an error in the solutions (this does happen, afterall the people who write the books are human too).

To check your work, instead of asking living people, you could simply ask a calculator.  [For example wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C0%2C5%2C2%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C-6%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C8%2C6%7D%7D) shows that your row reduction was indeed correct.

As to your question of when does a row of all zeroes *not* mean infinitely many solutions, that occurs when there are **no solutions**.

Below, all $\star$'s can be any number.

A row reduced augmented matrix of the form:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&\star&\star&\star\\0&1&\star&\star\\0&0&1&\star\end{array}\right]$

will have a unique solution.

A row reduced augmented matrix of the form $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&\star&\star&\star\\0&1&\star&\star\\0&0&0&\color{red}{\star}\end{array}\right]$ where $\color{red}{\star}\neq 0$ will have *no solutions*

A row reduced augmented matrix of the form:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&\star&\star&\star\\0&0&1&\star\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

will have infinitely many solutions.

A row reduced augmented matrix of the form $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&\star&\star&\star\\0&0&0&\color{red}{\star}\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

will have **no solutions**.  This is *despite* the row of all zeroes, since there is a row of zeroes followed by a nonzero number, the system is inconsistent in the first place.